# Question about dimension of Lie algebra of $\mathbb{R}$ with addition

Tags: lie-groups, vector-analysis, lie-algebras

I have read a fact that seem to be in conflict with my intuition. It is that when $\mathbb{R}$ is a group, the Lie algebra is also $\mathbb{R}$ because left invariant vector fields on the group are constant maps to $T\mathbb{R}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. This seems similar to the other fact that there is an isomorphism $\mathfrak{g} \cong T_e G$.

What confuses me is, should not $T_e \mathbb{R}$ be two dimensional, so we can have tangent *vectors*? Is this at all related to the fact that $\nabla \mathbb{R}$ is scalar values like when $\nabla f(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f$, or am I visualising this wrong?

Comment: Why you think that in order to have tangent vectors, $T_e\mathbb{R}$ should be two dimensional?

Comment: Well, following the visualisation I tried to explain, I guess they don't have to be... maybe it feels strange given how we are taught to visualise gradients as 2D vectors arising from the gradient of a scalar field, but I guess that doesn't matter here

Comment: It sounds as if you don't believe a one-dimensional vector space is truly a vector space ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space $T_e\Bbb R$ is the tangent space of $\Bbb R$ at the origin. But $\Bbb R$ is a $1$-dimensional manifold. Therefore, $\dim T_e\Bbb R=1$.